# UIPickerView Not Working In IOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios8, uipickerview

UIPickerView is Not Working In IOS 8 But it's working in IOS 7 without an error , here is my code 
one array having name myArray loads data in pickerview

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [sliderView addSubview:_myPickerView];

    txtstreet.inputView=_myPickerView;
    myArray = arrwithdata;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView: (UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
      return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

 return [myArray count];

}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)rowForComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return myArray[row];
}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
  inComponent:(NSInteger)component 
{

    NSString *resultString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", myArray[row]];
    txtstreet.text = resultString;
}
```

It's run in ios7 
Here is error when run in IOS 8 Device

```
2014-10-17 11:54:19.284 DispatchMe[2119:903697] *** Terminating app due to uncaught       
exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'child view controller:   
 <UICompatibilityInputViewController: 0x145553dc0> should have parent view controller: 
 <RegistrationVC: 0x14560e930> but requested parent is:<UIInputWindowController: 
0x146037a00>'
 ***  First throw call stack:

(0x183e8e084 0x19446c0e4 0x183e8dfc4 0x1886aa688 0x188d09e14 0x188d0a968 0x18861e77c  
 0x188d0a794 0x188d06924 0x1886d2180 0x188691b3c 0x188691e10 0x1887114e8 0x1887c2288 0x1887c18f0 0x1887a7768 0x188640184 0x188aa8f78 0x18860475c 0x188602b08 0x18863e32c 0x18863d9cc 0x1886111d4 0x1888af98c 0x18860f73c 0x183e46324 0x183e455c8 0x183e43678 0x183d71664 0x18ceb35a4 0x1886764f8 0x100058068 0x194adaa08)
 libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
 (lldb)
```

Comment: Are you usning Actionsheet to show Picker?

Comment: No , just show Picker View

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this by making programmatically picker-view , problem is in my view because i create two view one is main and second is sliderview , calling picker from view for slider view ,
now my code is look like this

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
 UIPickerView *myPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 320, 200)];
myPickerView.delegate = self;
myPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
 //[sliderView addSubview:_myPickerView];

txtstreet.inputView=_myPickerView;
myArray = arrwithdata;
}
```

and other code is same ... it's work in both os.

Answer (score 0):

Try one if two things.

1. Remove

   `[sliderView addSubview:_myPickerView];`

this code from `viewdidLoad` method.

2. If that does not work than put that code back in and alloc and init your pickerview in view did load method

   `_myPickerView = [UIPickerVuew alloc]init]`

Answer (score -1):

Try..

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0")) {

    alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil
                                                          message:@"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
                                                   preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
    //pickerView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 30);
    UIView *toolView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 305.0f, 44.f)];
    toolView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blank-headerNew.png"]];
    CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake(220, 5, 70, 30);
    UIButton *selButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:buttonFrame];
    //[selButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"red_bgnew.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [selButton setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [selButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [toolView addSubview:selButton];
    [alertController.view addSubview:pickerView];
    [alertController.view addSubview:toolView];
    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```